# UISearchDisplayController creates a UIPopovercontroller. How dismiss it?

Tags: ios, ipad, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

When I start taping in searchBar, the result popover appear. It's happen only on IPad, on iPhone everything work fine.
How can I dismiss this popover? I show result in my tableView, I don't need this popover.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    searchData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    originChannels = [[NSArray alloc]init];
    channels = [[NSArray alloc] init];

    searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc]
                             initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f,0.0f,320.0f,0.0f)];

    searchBar.placeholder =@"Search";
    searchDisplayController = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:searchBar contentsController:self];
[searchBar sizeToFit];
    searchDisplayController.delegate = self;
    searchDisplayController.searchResultsDataSource = self;

self.navigationItem.titleView = searchBar;
self.navigationItem.titleView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
}
```

Search:

```
-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{
    [self filterContentForSearchText:searchString
                           scope:[[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles]
                                  objectAtIndex:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar
                                                 selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];
    channels = searchData;
    if([searchString isEqualToString:@""])
    {
         channels = originChannels;
         [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
     }

     [self.tableView reloadData];
     [self.collectionView reloadData];
     return YES;
}
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{
    [searchData removeAllObjects];
    Channel *channel;
    for(channel in originChannels)
    {
        NSRange range = [channel.name rangeOfString:searchText
                                    options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
        if (range.length > 0)
           [searchData addObject:channel];
    }
}
```

This

```
[searchDisplayController setActive:NO animated:YES];
```

doesn't help me.

MY SOLUTION:

This fixed my issue

```
searchDisplayController.displaysSearchBarInNavigationBar=YES;
```

Comment: [self.searchDisplayController setActive:NO animated:YES];
[searchBar becomeFirstResponder];

Comment: @PushpakNarasimhan it did not help me:( it hid search string but not results popover